# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<WgService> above this landing widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Landing extends StatelessWidget {
  const Landing({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthService auth = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (contexta, snapshot) {
          FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
          WgService wg = Provider.of<WgService>(context);

          if (user == null)
            return LoginView();
          else
            return StreamBuilder<WGDocument>(
                stream: wg.streamWG('demowg'),
                builder: (contextWG, snapshotWG) {
                  WGDocument currentWG = snapshotWG.data;

                  if (currentWG != null)
                    return SignedInView();
                  else
                    return JoinWGScreen();
                });
        });
  }
}
```

I readed multiple issues with the same error but cant get it fixed by myself. I tried every other context and I do not understand why the error occurs. No IDE errors given.

Comment: Have you provided `AuthService` to your widget?

Comment: @easeccy what do you mean? the auth service worked fine the code stopped working after I added the part with the wg streambuilder

Comment: Have you used Provider widget as ancestor of this widget already?

Comment: @easeccy no, the code shown is the top level widget of the app

Comment: I supplied an answer, you need to use Provider widget to provide your business logic to the widget tree. It uses InheritedWidget under the hood. These are basics, I suggest you to dig in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a Provider widget on top of your widget. Then you build your widgets as an ancestor of that provider widget. Any descendant can reach the data class of that provider.

```
Provider<AuthService>(
  create: (_) => AuthService(),
  child: /* Any widgets below can reach AuthService */
)
```